# Fixed Search Box in Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'm trying to figure out how to make the search box fixed in the navigation bar instead of being part of the dropdown menu. The final output would be something similar to the image below.

[image: Bootstrap Nav]

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- add header -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

    </div>

    <!-- add menu -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="/services.html">Services</a></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- add search form -->
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search this site">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the code I'm currently working on: http://www.bootply.com/fb311f2zSJ#

Comment: Please include a shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem you are having in the question itself. As well, please remember to include a clear question statement. Its fine and dandy that you're telling us what you want to do, what we need to know is the problem you're having and what you would like us to do about it.

Comment: Just put the search form in navbar header and it won't collapse ever

Comment: its already there in dream weaver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.navbar-header form {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    max-width: 250px;
}
button.navbar-toggle.pull-left {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse, .navbar-inverse .navbar-form {
        border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
        margin-top: 0;
        padding-top: 8px;
    }
    .navbar-form {
        padding: 10px 15px;
        margin-top: 8px;
        margin-right: -15px;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
        margin-left: -15px;
        border-top: 0px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1),0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1);
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1),0 0px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- add header -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <!-- add search form -->
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search this site">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <!-- add menu -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="width:100%">
                <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="/services.html">Services</a></li>     
            </ul>    
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add another search form that will become visible on mobile devices. You can style it with your css to position the search bar properly.

Here is the updated html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- add header -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

      <!-- add the mobile devices search form here -->
     <div class="col-xs-10 visible-xs">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right mobile-search" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search this site" type="text">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
   <!-- end of the mobile devices search form section -->

    </div>

    <!-- add menu -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="/services.html">Services</a></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- add search form -->
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right hidden-xs" role="search">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search this site" type="text">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done some changes in default css file may this will help you.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- add header -->
        <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>


        </div>

        <!-- add menu -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="/services.html">Services</a></li>
            </ul>
          <!-- add search form -->


        </div>
         <form class="navbar-form navbar-right pull-right" role="search">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search this site">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
              </button>
            </span>
          </div>
      </form>

    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width:768px){
  .navbar-collapse{ 
    float:left
  }
}

@media (max-width:767px){
  .navbar-form.navbar-right{
        border-color: #101010;
        width: calc(100% - 30px);
        padding: 0;
        border: none;
   }
   .navbar{
     border:none;
   }
   .navbar-collapse{  
     background-color: #222;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50px;
     width: 100%;
     left:0;
     margin:0 !important;
   }
}
```

Here is working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/vb8ptav5/